# javascript ckeditor a.$.parentNode is null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a designer studio extension in eclipse. I have to build my whole application with javascript and d3 (including the HTML). I have to make a textarea that can be formatted with bold text, etc. So I was thinking of using CKEditor. I implemented all the files in the correct way and my paths are all correct. So this is my current code I'm working with

```
text = theDiagram.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("x", "0")
        .attr("y", "50")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .html('<div><textarea id="tekstvak" placeholder="enter some text here..." maxlength="1000" rows="5" cols="40" name="tekstvak" class="tekstvak"></textarea></div>');
        CKEDITOR.replace('tekstvak');
```

But everytime I run my custom component I get this error:

> TypeError: a.$.parentNode is null

I know my parentNode is null when I run my code, but I haven't found a way to fix this in javascript and d3.

Comment: Still not solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so for some reason if you directly try to implement the ckeditor you will get this error the way I worked around this is by doing the following:

```
var myVar = setTimeout(myTimer, 100);

        function myTimer() {



            testcdk = CKEDITOR.replace('tekstvak',{
                name:"cktekstak",
                id:"cktekstak",
                class:"cktekstak",
            });
            CKEDITOR.config.height = 210; 

        }
```

I don't know why but if I put a small delay on it, it works